# Java swing: renaming JMenu title based upon JMenuItem selection

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenuitem, jmenubar

Is it possible to rename the JMenu title using the selected JMenuItem?

I am using an ActionListener to do this:

```
public MenuBar(){
.
.
.
add(createMenu("Choose Bow: "));
.
.
.
public JMenu createmenu(String name){
JMenu menu = new JMenu(name);
JRadioButtonMenuItem bow = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Pink");
bow.setHorizontalTextPosition(JMenuItem.RIGHT);
bow.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
        String current = "Pink";
        add(createMenu(current));
        menu.revalidate();          
        }
    });

group.add(bow);
.
.
.
menu.add(bow);
menu.revalidate();

return menu;
}
```

I want the menu to say `Pink` instead of `Choose Bow:` but what I have written right now just keeps recreating a new menu on the MenuBar in addition to what I've already got.

Comment: You probably want a [`JComboBox`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

`JMenu menu = new JMenu(name);`

needs to change to:

`menu = new JMenu(name);` where `menu` is an instance member of the class:

`private JMenu menu;`

Then in `actionPerformed(...)`, simply call:

`menu.setText(current)` instead of re-creating it.

Comment: Dang I was just typing this out. Beat me to it. +1